# Store same sequence value in two columns

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table in which one column is auto increment sequence number. I want the same value to be stored in another column as well (so it can be changed later).

My table structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    test_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass),
    ...
    ...
    uid integer not null DEFAULT currval('test_id_seq'::regclass),
)
```

I want `uid = test_id` but the problem is when multiple row are inserted in one sessions. Then `currval` doesn't take the correct id.

I don't want to use a trigger. How can I manage it?

Comment: Multiple columns are inserted? Did you mean rows?

Comment: oh sorry multiple rows

Comment: But really, why do you need 2 columns to store the same value? Will one be changed later?

Comment: yes, one column is change later

Comment: Why don't you want to use a trigger?

Comment: "I don't want to use a trigger". Well, there's your problem. *"How do I start my car? I don't want to use the key."* Well, you could open it up and fiddle with some wires which could work on a really old car if you know what you're doing ... or you could use the key."

Comment: i am thinking some another technique to solve this issue. Is there any techniques more for this ? ? ?

Comment: Don't store the value redundantly to begin with. Leave it NULL until you have a different value to enter. Access with `COALESCE(uid, test_id)`. Or do you *need* it to be `NOT NULL`.

Comment: @SaddamKhan The only other technique you have is to move out this part of the logic to your application. Which probably makes a lot of sense if you know in advance that a stored value needs to be changed.

Comment: How does that matter if there are multiple inserts per session? It's not obvious what  kind of INSERTs queries fail to work with your current technique. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: in application multiple thread is running and multiple insert operations some time one query has been taken time at the moment another is executed, so this kinds of problem has been occured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to not rely at all on `currval`, you might transform the INSERT queries in systematic way following this pattern:

- To insert from a select, instead of :

  INSERT INTO Test(columns) SELECT columns FROM...;

  consider this form:

  ```
  INSERT INTO Test(test_id, uid, columns) 
  SELECT pk,pk,columns FROM
  (SELECT nextval('test_id_seq') as pk, columns FROM ...) AS alias;
  ```
- For a single row in a `VALUES` clause, instead of

  ```
  INSERT INTO Test(columns) VALUES(...values here...)
  ```

  consider:

  ```
  INSERT INTO Test(test_id, uid, columns...) 
  SELECT pk,pk,columns FROM
   (SELECT nextval('test_id_seq') as pk, ...values here...) AS alias;
  ```
- for VALUES clauses with multiple rows, instead of:

  ```
  INSERT INTO Test(columns) VALUES(...values1...),(...values2...)
  ```

  consider:

  ```
   WITH v(columns...) AS ( VALUES(...values1...),(...values2...) )
   INSERT INTO Test(test_id, uid, columns) 
   SELECT pk,pk,columns... FROM
    (SELECT nextval('test_id_seq') as pk, v.columns... FROM v) AS alias;
  ```

---

If PostgreSQL had a standard-compliant NEXTVAL, you could do without the subquery and just use something like:

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR seqname,
                       NEXT VALUE FOR seqname,
                       other columns...
```

and the `NEXT VALUE FOR seqname` would evaluate to the same value for both columns of the same output row, as mandated by the standard. But PostgreSQL does not have this construct.